# Scheduling Basic Consume in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using `RabbitMQ` from last month successfully.Messages are read from queue using BasicConsume feature of RabbitMQ.The messages published to queue is immediately consumed by the corresponding consumer.
Now i created a new queue DelayedMsg,The messages published to this queue has to be read only after 5 min delay.What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a current timestamp value to the message while publishing message to the main queue from publisher / sender. Say example, 'published_on' => 1476424186.

At the consumer side, first check the time difference of current timestamp and published_on.

If the difference found to be less than 5 minutes, then send your message in another queue ( a DLX queue ) with setting expiration time.( use 'expiration' property of amqp message )

This expiration value should be ( current timestamp - published_on ) and it should be in milliseconds.

The message will gets expired in the DLX queue on exact 5 min.

Make sure 'x-dead-letter-exchange' should be your main queue exchange and is bounded with the dlx queue so that when the message gets expired, it will automatically gets queued up back into the main queue. see [Dead Letter Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) for more details.

So, consumer now get the message back after 5 min, process it normally, since its current timestamp and published_on difference will be greater than 5 min.

Comment: @Bhimaro Gadge after the 5 minutes timeout in DLX queue whether the message will again re-queued to the main queue or consume from the DLX queue?

Comment: The expired message will get re-queued into the main queue and from there, it will get received / consumed by the consumer.

Comment: In my case, the requirement was complex. Not every message has to get delayed. There were some factors I had to check. So I put DLX requeue logic at consumer side.  If your requirement is really very simple as you mentioned, then I suggest go with other option that is send the message directly to DLX queue setting 5 min expiration on message or setting 5 min TTL on queue (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html). Bound this DLX queue with main exchange. The expired message then requeued in main queue after 5 min. And then the consumer will consume it.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding using DLX to implement delayed messages anymore. It is more like a workaround before having the "RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin."

Since now we have this plugin, we should try to use it instead:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/

Comment: This plugin shows some issues see :[link](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/issues)

Answer (score 0):

create 2 queues.
1 is work queue
2 is delay queue
and set delay queue property x-dead-letter-->work queue name,ttl-->5min
send message to delay queue,not need consumer it ,after 5min,this send the message to deal-letter(work queue),so you just consumer the work queue and process it